# Prove that if a formula  has property  , then the formula (∃ ) also has property  .

Tags: predicate-logic, substitution

[image]

I know that this statement is true, but don't know how to approach the proof.

Comment: Related post: [what-does-the-symbol $\mapsto$ mean-in-the-logical-expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308732/what-does-the-symbol-mapsto-mean-in-the-logical-expression-j-vdash-ex) for the symbolism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases:

*(i)* $x \ne y$, and so $x$ is free in $\exists y \ \beta$.

But then $x$ is free in $\beta$, and thus we have to apply the fact that $\beta$ has property $P$.

*(ii)* $x=y$. Thus: $(\exists y \ \beta)[a/y]= \exists y \ \beta$.

This means that $(\exists y \ \beta)[a/y]^{(I,E)}= (\exists y \ \beta)^{(I,E)}$.

Clearly $(\exists y \ \beta)^{(I,E)}$ is true iff some "$x$-variant" of $E$ satisfy $\exists y \ \beta$ in $I$. But an "$x$-variant" of $E$ is also an "$x$-variant" of $E(x \leftarrow a^I)$.

Thus:

> $(\exists y \ \beta)[a/y]^{(I,E)}=(\exists y \ \beta)^{(I,E(x \leftarrow a^I))}$